# How to remove color picker from frontend?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend

I'm building a theme based on the Blank theme, using the Magento UI library.

I notice that Magento comes with a color picker, which loads both *spectrum.js* (> 80 kB) and *tinycolor.js* (almost 40 kB). To be fair, these sizes are before minimizing the code, nevertheless this is still a massive amount of JavaScript, especially since my site doesn't have any use for a color picker in the first place.

Is there any way to remove / disable the color picker, such that I can avoid loading this unnecessary code?

Comment: do you want to remove those JS from front-end ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes, exactly. Why load JS that is not needed?

Comment: Hi @m4r73n Do you get the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can override bootstrap to remove color-picker.

Create a folder in theme with name Magento_Ui and override bootstrap.js file and remove below code

colorPicker:    require('./color-picker')

Answer (score 1):

did you ever find how to disable these useless scripts?? who the hell decided its good idea to force people to use all ui modules from jquery, I mean this is 50iq play

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

This totally resurecting an old thread but just had to do the exact same thing and found that you can accomplish this by overriding:

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap.js
```

And then removing the librarys not required from there